# making model in gazebo other than box, cylinder, and sphere

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi.

I have made code that Pioneer2dx follows a given trajectory.
In representing that trajectory, I want to use "arrow" or "triangle" to see the next direction.

To display "arrow" or "triangle" (It could be cylinder shape), what should I do?
I want to make them with default models(box, cylinder, and sphere), is that possible?
Is it possible that I cut the box in a diagonal direction to make triangular shape?

Any idea?
Thank you very much! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5082/making-model-in-gazebo-other-than-box,-cylinder,-and-sphere/) by [JOON](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/520/joon/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

You could import a triangle mesh, [here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/beginner/mesh_import) is a tutorial on how to import meshes.

Or, if you need only a visual of the arrow, you could create a [system plugin](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/plugins/camera_plugin) and add an arrow to the rendering.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JOON](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/520/joon/) on 2013-12-02**:
Thanks so much, It was really helpful! :)